# Undo Gypsy Plugin Failing on MSM Site

Tags: multi-site-manager, upgrade, gypsy

I'm trying to prep an ExpressionEngine 1.7 site for upgrade to ee2 and there are a number of Gypsy fields I need to convert. I'm trying to use the [undo_gypsy plugin](https://github.com/litzinger/UndoGypsy.eeaddon/blob/master/pi.undo_gypsy.php) but nothing happens when I follow the instructions. I've checked all the Group and Weblog IDs and the only thing I can think of is that maybe the site ID might need to be included?

There is no place for a site ID, so I'm stuck.When I run the tag in the new template, the page stays blank and I can't even get an error. I've tried only adding the specific weblogs for the site I'm on and run the template from that weblog and I've tried adding all the weblogs for all sites at the same time but neither seems to work. The new Field Groups have no new fields and the old Gypsy Fields are still there and plugin is still installed.